# How to make sidebar full height, including overflowed content with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to get a sidebar to be full page height. `100%` works fine.. but if the content area is greater than 100% the sidebar comes up short...

http://codepen.io/speg/pen/yNraNv

Looking for a simple and clean flex-box solution, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was overthinking this one.

Comment: We've all been there ;) glad I could help.